# How to hide form from an event in different thread

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, events, delegates

So I a main form and I want to Hide it if the client is connected so I,ve created an event who's called from another class, "Coms.class" I don't think you need all the code for the class but if you need just say it.

This is the function who's listening an event from the class Coms

***Main form :***

```
Private Sub sAuthentified(ByVal sender As Coms, ByVal sTemp As String) Handles mComs.sAuthentified
    If (Equals(sender.AES_Decrypt(sTemp), "$%?SuccesS&*(")) Then
        Me.Hide()

        Dim connected As New Connected(mComs)
        connected.ShowDialog()
        connected.Dispose()
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("NON")
    End If
End Sub
```

***Function where the event is raised in class coms :***

```
Private Sub Receiving(ByVal iAr As IAsyncResult)
        Dim bReader As BinaryReader
        Dim sReader As StreamReader
        Dim sReaderBuffer(iPacketSize) As Char
        Dim iReaded As Integer

        Try
            SyncLock _client.GetStream
                _client.GetStream.EndRead(iAr)
            End SyncLock
        Catch ex As Exception
            Exit Sub
        End Try

        Select Case bReadByte(0)
            Case enumTags.Connection
                SyncLock _client.GetStream
                    bReader = New BinaryReader(_client.GetStream)
                    iPacketSize = bReader.ReadInt16
                End SyncLock

                RaiseEvent connectionEstablished(Me)
                _client.GetStream.BeginRead(bReadByte, 0, 1, AddressOf Receiving, Nothing)

            Case enumTags.Authentication
                SyncLock _client.GetStream
                    sReader = New StreamReader(_client.GetStream)

                    iReaded = sReader.Read(sReaderBuffer, 0, iPacketSize)
                End SyncLock

                Dim sTemp As New String(sReaderBuffer, 0, iReaded)
                RaiseEvent sAuthentified(Me, sTemp)

                _client.GetStream.BeginRead(bReadByte, 0, 1, AddressOf Receiving, Nothing)
        End Select

    End Sub
```

So when the event is raised I get an error saying he need a delegate because it was called from another thread. That make sense since in the Coms class I have a Asynchronous read on a stream in a callback and the event is raised in the read so I guess it's normal

My problem is : I can't call Invoke on the function hide so I'm confuse on how to create the delegate

Need some helps thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call BeginInvoke with a delegate to your own method.  Which then just calls Hide().

That's not enough, you must also ensure that the ShowDialog() call is made from the UI thread.  So just make sure that the entire sAuthentified() method is invoked:

```
Private Sub sAuthentified(ByVal sender As Coms, ByVal sTemp As String) Handles mComs.sAuthentified
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.BeginInvoke(New Action(Of Coms, String)(AddressOf sAuthentified), sender, sTemp)
    Else
        '' Rest of your code here
        ''...
    End If
End Sub
```